# WhatsApp Calling feature

Tags: whatsapp, messaging, calls

When will the WhatsApp calling feature be available on Windows Phone?

Currently when someone with WhatsApp calling tries to call me using WhatsApp, they get a message saying that this contact needs to update WhatsApp. However, there are currently no updates for WhatsApp available on the store.

Comment: This is something only WhatsApp can answer - afaik they have not made an official statement when this feature will become available on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WhatsApp have confirmed that this feature is "in the works" for Windows Phone, although no ETA has been given.

> WhatsApp Calling for your platform is still in the works. Unfortunately, we cannot comment on any future release timelines but we appreciate your interest in WhatsApp Calling.

Source: [WMPU](http://wmpoweruser.com/whatapp-confirms-whatsapp-calling-for-windows-phone-still-in-the-works)

**Update:** Calling functionality is now availably in the WhatsApp beta version, [according to Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/latest-whatsapp-beta-build-finally-adds-calling-functionality).

**Update 2:** The Calling feature should now be available to everyone, [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/whatsapp-finally-brings-voice-calling-masses) reports.